# C++: check if string is a valid integer using "strtol"

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, error-handling, strtol

I have heard that I should use `strtol` instead of `atoi` due to its better error handling. I wanted to test out `strtol` by seeing if I could use this code to check if a string is an integer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string testString = "ANYTHING";
    cout << "testString = " << testString << endl;
    int testInt = strtol(testString.c_str(),NULL,0);
    cout << "errno = " << errno << endl;
    if (errno > 0)
    {
        cout << "There was an error." << endl;
        cout << "testInt = " << testInt << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Success." << endl;
        cout << "testInt = " << testInt << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I replaced `ANYTHING` with `5` and it worked perfectly:

```
testString = 5
errno = 0
Success.
testInt = 5
```

And when I do it with `2147483648`, the largest possible `int` + 1 (2147483648), it returns this:

```
testString = 2147483648
errno = 34
There was an error.
testInt = 2147483647
```

Fair enough. But, when i try it with `Hello world!`, it incorrectly thinks it's a valid `int` and returns `0`:

```
testString = Hello world!
errno = 0
Success.
testInt = 0
```

Notes:

- I am using Code::Blocks with GNU GCC Compiler on Windows
- "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]" is checked in "Compiler Flags".

Comment: Pass appropriate argument instead of `NULL` to [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to know the valid range.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/021660de72cf66f4) for your 2nd test case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, It depends whether `long` can hold that number. A 32-bit `long` cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According with [the man page of `strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html). You must define your function such as:

```
bool isNumeric(const std::string& str) {
    char *end;
    long val = std::strtol(str.c_str(), &end, 10);
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (val == LONG_MAX || val == LONG_MIN)) || (errno != 0 && val == 0)) {
        //  if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type.
        return false;   
    }
    if (end == str) {
       // No digits were found.
       return false;
    }
    // check if the string was fully processed.
    return *end == '\0';
}
```

In C++11, I prefer to use `std::stol` instead of `std::strtol`, such as:

```
bool isNumeric(const std::string& str) {
    try {
        size_t sz;
        std::stol(str, &sz);
        return sz == str.size();
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument&) {
        // if no conversion could be performed.
        return false;   
    } catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
        //  if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type.
        return false;
    }
}
```

`std::stol` calls `std::strtol`, but you works directly with `std::string` and the code is simplified.

Comment: i heard that `try` should be avoided when possible

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5, the current best practice on try/catch is that robust readable code should be preferred above all else so sometimes try/catch will be the option. Also some of the new C++11 library features require try/catch to get the desired functionality as in the example above with `std::stol`.

Comment: Your first code snippet did the job, however, i suggest you call the function "isInt" as is does not count decimal numbers as numeric

Comment: also, in your second snippet, i get `error: 'stol' was not declared in this scope`, even with including `iostream`, `string`, `string.h`, `cstring`, `stdlib.h`  and `stdio.h`.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5. You must compile with C++11 `g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cc -o your_program` and including `string` header.

Answer (score 3):

strtol stops on the first non digit

but if you read the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html you can see

> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first
>          invalid character in *endptr.  If there were no digits at all,
>          strtol() stores the original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns
>          0).  **In particular, if *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on
>          return, the entire string is valid**.

ie

```
string testString = "ANYTHING";
cout << "testString = " << testString << endl;
char *endptr;
int testInt = strtol(testString.c_str(),&endptr,0);
if(**endptr)
   cout << "bad input";
```

Comment: `error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'char')` and i have made sure to use this patch (all 3 files): http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the C++11 way solution with exceptions, because it is slower. Here is a fast C++11 version:

```
#include <algorithm>
bool is_decimal(const std::string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){ return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end(); 
}
```

If you are sure that your strings mostly are not empty, then you can delete *!s.empty()*. If you are not, keep it because *!s.empty()* (*!(s.length()==0)*) is cheaper than if you call *find_if* ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)) with an empty string.

Edit:
If you have to handle overflow use the exception version above. Only if you can not use exceptions use this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

template <class T>
bool is_decimal_and_fit(const std::string& s)
{
    long double decimal = 0;
    return (!(std::istringstream(s) >> decimal).fail() && (decimal >= std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()) && (decimal <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max())); 
}
```

Comment: It just checks if it only has digits. I need to be able to confirm if the number overflows for signed/unsigned. Should I just stick to the other methods provided?

Comment: Just use this:

bool is_decimal(const std::string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){ return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end(); 
}

Comment: sorry, shift + enter does not work in this quick comment I can not delete it :)

Comment: then post it as an answer